# How to safely delete a system partition?

Tags: partition, grub2, shared-disk

I got the following disk

[image]

`sda9` contains a new Linux installation which I'd like to keep, while `sda5` is the old installation which I'd like to **free** (and successively merge with `sda4`, but we don't care).

`sda4` contains a Windows installation which I'd like to keep.

The question, made to be sure of **avoiding (grub) problems at boot**, is:

*do I need just to delete* `sda5` *without any other operation, and nothing will break ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you run

```
sudo update-grub
```

**immediately after** you make any changes to the partition table. That is not necessary in some cases but it is always safe to do it.

In your case it is better to make all changes from your new Linux installation: delete a partition and then update grub.

If you are going to use Live CD instead you need to update grub by [chroot-ing](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) to your new Linux installation (you don't need to reinstall it, only update).

That *should* work unless you made any unsafe changes to your configuration files (e.g., if you ever made any changes to /etc/fstab, you **must** check that all partitions there are identified by UUID, not by their names).

Anyway to be on the safe side it is always better to have Live CD in case something goes wrong. Good luck!